# NPM install shows error

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, npm-install

I have tried to uninstall and reinstall angular cli, for which i have used,

```
sudo npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Whenever i give **npm install** it is showing the error,

```
npm ERR! Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 while parsing near '
npm ERR! <!doctype html>
npm ERR! <htm...'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/izchnl050/.npm/_logs/2018-08-07T08_02_19_674Z-debug.log
```

And the log file consists the following,

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/usr/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   '-g',
1 verbose cli   '@angular/cli' ]
2 info using npm@6.2.0
3 info using node@v10.8.0
4 verbose npm-session 6b584ff5794304f7
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readGlobalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://www.npmjs.com/@angular%2fcli 1450ms (from cache)
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for @angular/cli@latest Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 while parsing near '
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData <!doctype html>
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData <htm...'
9 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 1ms
10 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 1690ms
11 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 while parsing near '
11 verbose stack <!doctype html>
11 verbose stack <htm...'
11 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
11 verbose stack     at parseJson (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/json-parse-better-errors/index.js:7:17)
11 verbose stack     at consumeBody.call.then.buffer (/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-fetch-npm/src/body.js:96:50)
11 verbose stack     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
12 verbose cwd /home/izchnl050
13 verbose Linux 4.15.0-29-generic
14 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
15 verbose node v10.8.0
16 verbose npm  v6.2.0
17 error Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1 while parsing near '
17 error <!doctype html>
17 error <htm...'
18 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Based on the other solutions, tried with the following,

```
npm cache clean --force
```

Uninstalled node and again installed node but there is no use.

If i give npm install it showing the above error everytime.

```
npm -v = 6.2.0
node -v = v10.8.0
```

Kindly help me to fix this issue and to continue with the workflow.

Comment: could you downgrade node version and try again??

Comment: Seems like there is a connection issue and the request returns a HTML error page. Do you have an active internet connection? Are you behind a corporate proxy and if so, did you configure NPM proxy settings?

Comment: @UnluckyAj, IN node version 8 itself it throws the same error. Then only i have upgraded to node v 10..

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? if you are add the proxy settings to npm. Or if that doen't work maybe you're using non-standard npm registry. check the registry url as well

Comment: When using a custom npm registry, you might need to authenticate first.

Comment: Tried it in my local workspace using the same version of node and npm. And, I am able to install angular CLI without any problem. I assume that your problem is because there is some kind of proxy or you need to authenticate first before you're able to use internet (something akin to captive portal)...

Answer (score -2):

try to remove package.lock file

Possible duplicate  [Install error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17340)

`package-lock.json is automatically generated for any operations where npm modifies either the node_modules tree, or package.json. It describes the exact tree that was generated, such that subsequent installs are able to generate identical trees, regardless of intermediate dependency updates.`

Delete the package-lock.json and after this run `npm install`.

Then you can install any plugin, that you want, with npm.

Comment: I am unable to install @angular/cli itself, Then where to remove ```package.lock```?

Comment: rm -f package-lock.json && npm install

Comment: also, if that doesn’t work, try

rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Comment: I am not having any angular projects to remove the files you said.. I am trying to install angular alone and i am not talking about any projects..